# how details of current location is shown on mkMapview?

Tags: iphone, ios, mkmapview, userlocation

I just want to show the current location in mkMapView and the map is centered at current location and coordinates and address info should also be displayed.How it can be achieved.By using showCurrentlocation to YES shows the blue pointer and shows the informaiton "current location".But,I want the detailed info on clicking that blue button.please help me.

Answer (score 1):

In the viewForAnnotation method of your MKMapViewDelegate(you have also to generate the addresses with the reverse geocoding)you could try this:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)map:(MKMapView *)map viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>) annotation{
    if(self._mapView.userLocation==annotation){
       self._mapView.userLocation.title=@"yourCityObtainedByReverseGeocoding";
       self._mapView.userLocation.subtitle=@"yourStreetObtainedByReverseGeocoding";
       return nil;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: i am using the reveseGeocoding but no information is getting..rather failing plaemark is shown. How can I do reverseGeocoding and also if i will get the reversegeocoding data.Then How can i put that calculated data in place of title and subtitle...plz give me a sample code....thanks in advance...